# Best way to capture Images from device's native camera in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, camera, html5-video

I need to know the best/recommended way to capture image from a device's camera using HTML5. I'm aware that I can use the below syntax to capture image from the camera. However, this launches the device camera once the button is clicked and doesn't wait for user's consent.

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*"  capture />
```

Excerpt from http://www.w3.org/TR/capture-api/#security.

> "The user agent should not enable any device for media capture, such
>   as a microphone or camera, until a user interaction giving implicit
>   consent is completed. A user agent should also provide an indication
>   when such an input device is enabled and make it possible to terminate
>   such capture."

The other option would be to use navigator.getUserMedia. However, it's cumbersome as I have to obtain a snapshot of live feed and copy to a canvas and save it as an Image. Moreover, the resolution is restricted in this case.

Which one should I go for? I read somewhere online that the first approach is deprecated, but I couldn't get that link to justify. My requirement is just to capture an image using the device camera and post it to a server. I do not need to embed the image real time too.

Comment: "However, this launches the device camera once the button is clicked and doesn't wait for user's consent." How is this not waiting for the user's consent? Once he clicks the button, he gives the application permission. I think w3c means that you shouldn't enable the camera on the background without notifying the user.

Comment: Excerpt from The Media Capture API Draft - "This is a draft document and may be updated, replaced or obsoleted by other documents at any time. It is inappropriate to cite this document as other than work in progress." - So should I go ahead and use this or wait till a reliable/finalized API is put in place?